# Updating optional fields with single query. mongoose & expressjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have user settings page and I want to allow the user update multiple fields from the user Schema. Is it possible to update the User Collection Item with a single query based on what fields have been updated.

The route

```
exports.updateUser = function(req, res){

  User.update({_id: '123'}, {
    $set: {
      mail: req.body.mail,
      name: req.body.name,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      age: req.body.age
      // ... and so on
    }
  })
}
```

If the user updates only the email than all other fields are null or undefined.

Is there any way of updating only the fields that are presented in the req.body without overwriting the db item with null values.

I know it possible to create an If statement for each field, but maybe there is a better solution for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
exports.updateUser = function(req, res){

  User.update({_id: '123'}, {
    $set: req.body
  })
}
```

As long as your `req.body` doesn't have anything extra in it. Might want to validate that first.

Comment: So it will update, only the fields available in req.body? sounds pretty straightforward :) thanks!

Comment: Yes but you are essentially giving your user free reign to add whatever they like. You'll want to validate the info in `req.body` first.